# Merge 2 doublet records together before deleting the doublet record

Tags: sql, database, t-sql

I have a table in my database with productinstances in it. The tables name is `productinstance` with the columns `id, imei, invoicedate, invoiceNo, serialNr, debitStartDate`.

In this table about 68 instances have a doublet (the same `imei` nr). I want to delete the doublet.
The problem is that there is info on the doublet that I need in the original record, so Before I delete the doublet I would like to merge the 2 records together.

On all the original records `invoiceNo` and `invoicedate` are `null`, And on all the doublet `serialno` have a null value.

So i would like to take the value  of `invoiceNo` and `invoicedate` from the dublet post merge it into the original record and then delete the doublet.

Is this possible. If yes how?

Comment: you can use a trigger

Answer (score 0):

Not very sure below is what you are looking for, you'd better provider us with some exmaples, but if it is, here is one of the way to achieve :to add an extra column for the derived field.

```
ALTER TABLE productinstance
ADD ExtraColumn as ISNULL(invoiceNo,'') + ISNULL(CAST(invoicedate) as VARCHAR(50),'')
```

Then you can delete any records based on the merged column.

Answer (score 0):

One simple way to do it is by using a self join for the update statement and another self join for the delete statement:

```
UPDATE t0
SET invoiceNo = t1.invoiceNo,
    invoicedate = t1.invoicedate
FROM productinstance t0
INNER JOIN productinstance t1 ON t0.imei = t1.imei
WHERE t0.invoiceNo IS NULL
AND t0.invoicedate IS NULL
AND t1.invoiceNo IS NOT NULL
AND t1.invoicedate IS NOT NULL


DELETE t0
FROM productinstance t0
INNER JOIN productinstance t1 ON t0.imei = t1.imei
                             AND t0.invoiceNo = t1.invoiceNo
                             AND t0.invoicedate = t1.invoicedate
AND t0.serialno IS NULL
```